Perform an automaticall search with every character pressed in Notepad++
In modern code editors when You perform ctrl + f and You start to type then with every key press application is performing the search. In Notepad++ You have to press Enter.
How do you make it perform a search after every keypress?

Notepad++ provides the "incremental search" feature for this. You will find it in the "Search" menu or you can start it with the hotkey CtrlAlti.
With the regular search dialog that opens with Ctrlf this will not work in Notepad++.

Thank You! This was the answer that I exactly looked for. Sorry for posting it on StackOverflow, but I hope someone will find this question useful.
